# A response to Rav Reuven - Bava Basra

Tags: talmud-gemara, rishonim, bava-batra

In the 6th daf of Bava Basra, we find the following case:

> מאי איריא ברשות הרבים אפילו רשות היחיד נמי רשות הרבים איצטריכא ליה מהו דתימא נימא ליה סוף סוף הא בעית לאצטנועי מבני רשות הרבים
> The Gemara asks: Why discuss specifically the case of two houses on opposite sides of a public domain, considering that the same halakha should apply even if the two houses are separated by a private domain? The Gemara answers: It was necessary for Abaye to mention a public domain, lest you say that one neighbor can say to the other: Ultimately, you need to conceal yourself from people in the public domain. Since in any event you have to build a fence across your entire roof, you cannot compel me to build a fence on my roof.
> https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.6b.4

And the peirushim argue whether it's an issue of נזק גופו or נזק ממון.

In the חידושי רבי ראובן, he offers the following:

> ונראה לומר דהצד השני דבסברא זו הוא דפליג וכ"מ מתנ"ר בריש מכילתין וכך מוכח מלשון הגמינן רשות הרבים איצטריכא לי' מהו דתימא נימא לי' סוף סוף הא בעית לאיצטנועי מבני רה"ר קמ"ל והנה אם ההיזק הוא מה שמצטער כשיראהו והטענה היא סוף לא יעשה מילי דהצנע משום בני רה"ר ומדקאמרינן סוף סוף וכו' משמע דמה שהוא צריך לעשות מעקה היינו נמי מה"ט דבשבילו ימנע ממילי דהצנע וכדפירש ר' גרשום סוף סוף אי לא הואי אנא הכא אפ"ה קבעית לאיצטנרער וכן פירש הרמ"ה

Essentially, whilst at first glance it seems to be נזק גופו, that doesn't fit with our הוה אמינא, as with נזק גופו, how can the מזיק claim that it's fine for him to be damaging the ניזק just because other people in the רה״ר are? Whereas with נזק ממון, it makes sense for the מזיק to make this claim: "as people are already preventing you from doing your business, it doesn't matter that I'm adding onto that."

This is a really strong question on those who claim the case is נזק גופו (such as the רמב״ן), and I've yet to think of a good response or find one in the achronim defending this stance.

Does anyone here know of one/can think of one?

Comment: Your Hebrew text is unedited I am having a hard time.

Comment: Something is wrong with Hebrew text. Please clear it up to make sure no one misunderstanda anything

Comment: Thank you for bringing this question here! Some individuals wait around for questions like these! Just a little more touching up...

Comment: Why can’t it be, that the mazik is saying, if I wanted to see what your doing I could go down to street and look. Being on the roof is no different than being on the street. Therefore the ability to cause the tzar is there regardless. Not necessarily from other people, but because he himself has the option.